# MySQL recursion query/statement required

Tags: mysql, recursion

How do I count the tickets for every category?
The main-categories should include every subcategory-ticket.

Tables:

```
ticket(id, category_id)
category(id, name, parentcategory_id)
```

I need a MySQL query. Is it possible with MySQL and this table-structure? If not, how?

Sample data:

```
ticket(1,1); 
ticket(2,2); 
ticket(3,3);
ticket(4,2);

category(1, 'Hardware', NULL)
category(2, 'Printer', 2)
category(3, 'Software', NULL)
```

So I have:

```
Software - 1 Ticket
Printer - 2 Tickets
Hardware - 1 Main Ticket, 2 Sub Tickets = 3 Tickets
```

Comment: ticket table does not have category_id?

Comment: Ohh, right, sorry. The ticket table has a category_id.

Comment: Can you also post the `show create table ticket` and `show create table category` outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT C.name AS 'Category', COUNT(ticket.id) AS 'Ticket Count'  
FROM ticket
JOIN category AS C ON C.id = ticket.category_id
GROUP BY C.name
```

This query joins your two tables together based on their common field (category_id foreign key for category table) and counts all the tickets for each category. GROUP BY groups an aggregate function.
To find subcategories based on your comments use this query

```
    SELECT C.name AS 'Sub-Category', COUNT(ticket.id) AS 'Ticket Count'  
    FROM ticket
    JOIN category AS C ON C.id = ticket.category_id
WHERE C.categoryparentid IS NULL
    GROUP BY C.name
```

you can use union to have them both at once

Comment: This only shows me the count from every category.
But I want a recursive statement. Every sub-category count should be added in the main-category count

Comment: I thought that is what you need

Comment: @KateGregory just added some explanation. Thanks

Comment: @6EQUJ5HD209458b can you show the subcategory table? and give us some sample data?

Comment: Sample Data are now available.

Comment: how do you distinguish between sub category and primary category? it would have been better if subcategories where on a separate table

Comment: If parentcategory_id is NULL then it's a primary category.
I can't add a separate table. The table-structure is fixed.

Comment: @6EQUJ5HD209458b please see the revised query

Comment: Please note ... Implicit sorting by GROUP BY is deprecated in MySQL 5.6 and will be removed in the future... if you not need the overhead of sorting use  ORDER BY NULL  after GROUP BY statement